# Page loading div display once per session and fade out when page is loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to setup a 'Page loading' div that displays fullscreen while the page is loading in, then fades out when the document is ready.

I have this working fine like so...

```
/*HTML*/
<div id="splash">Content</div>

/*CSS*/
#splash {
    background: url("http://localhost/images/loader.gif") no-repeat scroll center center #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:100000000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/*jQUERY*/

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#splash').fadeOut(800);
    $('body').css('overflow','auto');
});
</script>
```

The above setup essentially displays an animated graphic over the top of my loading site and then it fades out when the site has fully loaded. No issues here.

***WHAT I NEED***
I'd like the div to only show once per session (to avoid it showing when navigating back to the homepage from any other page on the site)

I wouldn't mind using a cookie or the html5 localstorage method.. I've just struggled for hours to try and piece together existing code and failed because my understanding of jQuery is rubbish.

Much appreciated

Comment: Well, you could start learning jQuery a bit more, by learning how to check for non-existance of a (session) cookie (before setting the fadeOut), and setting the session cookie after the fadeout.
Good luck!

Comment: Not quite the answer I was hoping for, but thanks for chiming in Pieter21. If I had enough knowledge of jQuery I'm sure your answer would probably point me in the right direction... unfortunately I don't and learning enough to pull this off would demand more hours than I have to complete the task. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some jsfiddling: http://jsfiddle.net/jf1yzLeg/1/

You have to make sure you include some cookie library, since it is not default jquery functionality.
I used: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js

Then you can use something like:

```
var cexists = $.cookie('cookie');

if (!cexists) {
    alert('will create cookie');

    $('#cexists').fadeOut(2000); // fade the other
    $.cookie('cookie', 'true', {
        expires: 1 // day
    });
} else {
    alert('cookie exists');
    $('#ncexists').fadeOut(2000); // fade the other
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for taking the time, I really appreciate it! I've been trying to tweak your fiddle but still can't get it to work how I need. Here's what I have... http://jsfiddle.net/bevels/aksraoru/1/

Comment: Almost killed another day doing something I'm sure would take others a matter of seconds.. painful! But hey, I'm learning as I go, so it's all good - I feel like I'm getting close with this latest update. It just doesn't seem to want to fade out #wrapper when the cookie is in effect. http://jsfiddle.net/bevels/aksraoru/8/

Comment: Yeah.. got there in the end and learned a ton along the way!! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Pieter21 - Here's the final working code.

http://jsfiddle.net/bevels/aksraoru/12/

Comment: Somehow your solution does not seem to behave as I'd expect on my PC, but glad it worked out for you.
Upvote or mark as answer would be nice ;) , for me, and for future readers on stackoverflow that they can proceed in this direction if they have a similar problem.

Comment: I've tested it across all browsers on PC and it seems to work exactly as I expect. Could you explain what's not working for you so I can make certain it'll behave correctly. Thanks Pieter21

Comment: I don't know what you exactly want and how to test it, but I only see a dark gray window, with probably one nbsp on your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bevels/aksraoru/12/

Comment: Ahh yes, okay sorry about the confusion. Of course it won't work in the fiddle as it requires jquery.cookie.js - Basically it shows a div (a graphic site loader in this case) only if the cookie hasn't been set on the users device. If the cookie is set, it doesn't show the loader. This prevents the loader from firing momentarily when the user is browsing back to the homepage from any other section of the site. Thanks again.